# Is there a proper way to promisify arangojs?

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird, arangodb

I'd like to use arangojs 3.4.2 in my project. Since 3.0 there are no promises used by the driver.
After trying several libs to promisify the driver i have no success (bluebird,promisify-node...): each time the driver returns a new instance that instance is not promisified, and i have to promisify the new instance again to use with promises:

```
var Promise=require('bluebird');
var arango=require('arangojs');
db=Promise.promisifyAll(new arango("http://localhost:8529"));
/*db is promisified properly*/
testdb=db.databaseAsync('test').then(function(testInstance){
    /*
    the testInstance returned by the driver is not promisified
    to use it with promises i've to promisify again
    */
})
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is correct.

If you want to promisify all the methods of all the objects in the driver, you need to promisify the prototypes' methods directly:

```
var Database = require('arangojs/lib/Database');
Promise.promisifyAll(Database.prototype);

var db = new Database('http://localhost:8529');
db.databasesAsync().then(function (databases) {
  databases.forEach(function (database) {
    assertTrue(typeof database.databaseAsync === 'function');
  });
});
```

Comment: Ok, this works, but the use of the driver is complicated in this way, isn't it? I hope that the next version of the driver will have builtin support for  promises  (i wish builtin support: return a promise when no callback). Our full server side stack based on the old driver, and it is a big pain to convert it all. Also a problem with external promisification, that non-async functions will be promisified (and maybe useless) too (ex: `db.route` to `db.routeAsync`). When you call `db.routeAsync('_api/database')` it will return a promise which never be fullfilled nor rejected

Comment: True. The goal of arangojs is to provide a lightweight low-level driver on top of which heavier, more feature-rich APIs can be built. Until ES6 promises are widely supported, bundling a promise implementation adds too much weight (and opinion). I'm considering a workaround that adds optional promise support, though. See https://github.com/arangodb/arangojs/issues/26 for discussion.

Comment: I will take a look to the github issue. Your answer is the way to go in the given circumstances, so i accept it.

Answer (score 0):

> As of version 3.5, if the global Promise constructor is defined when an asynchronous function is called, the function will also return a promise.

https://github.com/arangodb/arangojs